# How do i create variable from inputbox

Tags: excel, vba, loops, inputbox

I am new at vba and i want to make a macro for my daily routine. I successfully manage big part of them with your helps here, but i stuck a section.

What i want : I have a analysis file, and it comes with months, beginning of code i am asking how many months have in file and want to know which of them.

```
    Sub Makro2()

howmanymonths= Application.InputBox(prompt:=ActiveSheet.Name & " how many months?", Type:=1)

For first = 1 To howmanymonths

nay = Application.InputBox(prompt:=ActiveSheet.Name & " First?", Type:=1)

Next first 

End Sub
```

For example, there are totally 3 months and i answered first "3",then next question i replyed "7" so nay = 7, but when its in loop next will be "8" and "9"

but how i can create nay1, nay2,nay3 or till what last months.

Maybe a better solution? Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm sorry but I cannot understand properly your question. I got the part where you ask how many months, but I do not uderstand the `nay` part. You created a loop that will ask you the value of `nay` for every month. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Use Dictionary to store values. `dict.add Key, Value`. you can retrieve values by key as dict(keys)

Comment: yes @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns "nay" is a variable, it become nay1 nay2 nay3....

Comment: @nagarajannd sorry i am new didnt understand dict.add Key? How i can use in code?

Comment: You need an Array then :) Check this-> https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create new variables in a sub, while running the sub. And in general you do not need to. If you do not know how many units do you need, you may use an `Array()` or `List()` and add elements to them:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim howManyMonths As Long
    howManyMonths = Application.InputBox(prompt:=ActiveSheet.Name & Months count?",Type:=1)

    Dim firstMonth As Long
    firstMonth = Application.InputBox(prompt:=ActiveSheet.Name & " First?", Type:=1)

    Dim someArray() As Long
    Dim cnt As Long

    ReDim someArray(howManyMonths - 1)

    For cnt = LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray)
        someArray(cnt) = firstMonth + cnt
    Next cnt

    For cnt = LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray)
        MsgBox someArray(cnt)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess this is what i look for, i am trying it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example for storing multiple data in dictionary and retrieve them using their key.

```
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
howmanymonths = Application.InputBox(prompt:=ActiveSheet.Name & " how many months?", Type:=1)

For first = 1 To howmanymonths
    'Key is nay + numberindex
    dict.Add "nay" & CStr(first), Application.InputBox(prompt:=ActiveSheet.Name & " First?", Type:=1)
Next first

MsgBox dict("nay1")
MsgBox dict("nay2")
MsgBox dict("nay3")
```